# angular ng-disable checkbox not update with dynamic source

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have several checkboxes dynamicaly generated from array source:

```
        /*js*/
        $scope.arrondissements =   JSON.parse('
    [{"name":"4e","checked":false,"disable":true},  
    {"name":"5e","checked":false,"disable":false},  
    {"name":"11e","checked":false,"disable":false},  
    {"name":"12e","checked":false,"disable":false},  
    {"name":"13e","checked":false,"disable":false},  
    {"name":"14e","checked":false,"disable":false},  
    {"name":"15e","checked":false,"disable":false},  
    {"name":"16e","checked":false,"disable":false},  
    {"name":"17e","checked":false,"disable":false},  
    {"name":"18e","checked":false,"disable":false},  
    {"name":"19e","checked":false,"disable":false},  
    {"name":"20e","checked":false,"disable":false}]');


        <!-- HTML -->
        <div ng-repeat="item  in arrondissements" class="checkbox-inline ">
             <label>
             <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="{{item.disable == true}}"
                      value="{{item.checked}}" ng-model="item.checked" >
              <span>{{item.name}}</span>
             </label>
        </div>
```

Checkboxes are generated correctly but When source gets updated , checkbox doesn't update

```
/*js*/
$scope.disableCb = function () {
      $scope.arrondissements[5].disable = true;
      $scope.arrondissements[6].disable = true;
      $scope.arrondissements[7].disable = true;
}

<!-- HTML -->
<button ng-click="disableCb()">disable</button>
```

Could you tell me why and how to fix it?

I made a Plunker :  http://plnkr.co/edit/jD1l3NgJuduTOoskpeVM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should define your $scope.disableCb function inside your controller function.

```
function controller( $scope) {
    var vm = $scope;

     $scope.title = 'controller';

$scope.arrondissements =   JSON.parse('[{"name":"4e","checked":true,"disable":true},{"name":"5e","checked":false,"disable":false},{"name":"11e","checked":false,"disable":false},{"name":"12e","checked":false,"disable":false},{"name":"13e","checked":false,"disable":false},{"name":"14e","checked":false,"disable":false},{"name":"15e","checked":false,"disable":false},{"name":"16e","checked":false,"disable":false},{"name":"17e","checked":false,"disable":false},{"name":"18e","checked":false,"disable":false},{"name":"19e","checked":false,"disable":false},{"name":"20e","checked":false,"disable":false}]');

$scope.disableCb = function () {

         $scope.arrondissements[5].disable = true;
         $scope.arrondissements[6].disable = true;
         $scope.arrondissements[7].disable = true;
      }

    }
```

I've also fixed how you used your directives. I've removed the `value` attribute on the checkboxes since they're redundant with `ng-model`. 
I've fixed your usage of ng-disabled as well

```
 <div ng-repeat="item  in arrondissements" class="checkbox-inline ">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="item.disable"
                                ng-model="item.checked" >
                        <span>{{item.name}}</span>
                    </label>
                </div>

              <button ng-click="disableCb()">disable</button>
```

see my fork on your plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/v1fwlf7QH0189WAhv6qM?p=preview